# SwipeUp and Swiping Right not working correctly on XCUITest - M1 Mac

Tags: ios, xctest, apple-m1, xcuitest, xcode13

On an intel computer, my XCUITest test works perfectly fine to swipe left and swipe right on a cell using cell.swipeRight() or cell.swipeLeft().

On my m1 computer, cell.swipeLeft() works but cell.swipeRight() doesn't.  I don't think it swipe right enough.  If I manually do it on the simulator then it works to hide the elements shown on swipe; however the swipeRight function won't swipe it enough to hide the elements.

Note: i'm running the simulator using Rosetta.  It works fine manually but not thru the XCTest functions

Does anyone have a solution for swiping right on the m1?

Also, swipeUp() on the Intel scrolls the table up a lot more than on the simulator using an m1 mac.  It just moves the table up a little now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have both machines so i can't replicate what's causing this, but i can offer you a workaround.

Use `.press` and define the swiping yourself.

```
let dragBegin = cell.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.1, dy: 0.5))
let dragEnd = cell.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.4, dy: 0.5))
dragBegin.press(forDuration: 0.1, thenDragTo: dragEnd)
```

Adjust `dx` for each `CGVector` as needed. These are coordinates are relative to the Cell (or any other XCUIElement) you're interacting with.

You can be very specific with this and even set `velocity` and `holdDuration`. ([See Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuicoordinate/3551692-press))

P.s. Chances are this is Apples bug. Consider opening a [Bugreport](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/).

Comment: I have this exact same problem - running the Simulator using Rosetta (on an M1 Pro MacBook Pro). This solution didn't work for me - like reutsey I can manually swipe the cell if I put a breakpoint in my tests but both this method and swipeLeft() do nothing. Interestingly if I try and use the record function to do the test it crashes. Had anyone found a solution?

Comment: Sorry Mike I have not yet :(